# Select Word boundaries in TextMate

Tags: macos, textmate

The command Select Word in TextMate considers certain characters to be word boundaries.  The most frustrating is - [hyphen] which makes variables that contain a hyphen to be unselectable.  Less egregious is $ making selecting the full variable in PHP somewhat annoying.

Has anyone come across a solution for this, like maybe a bundle that implements their own version of word selection?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Preferences > Text Editing and change the options under "Word Characters".